# Noun+adjective references

Tags: грамматика, склонение, согласование

I need your help with this. I know how to conjugate the adjectives but I am in desperate need for some kind of reference where I can see how and read about how the noun is adapated with an appropriate ending in combination with the adjective (in G., D., I. and L. classes). Right now I have pieces of fragments and it makes me somewhat frustrated. I would highly appreciate any references.

Comment: That's a non-issue. A noun always declines the same way, adjective or no adjective. Adjectives adapt to nouns (in gender, number, and animacy), not the other way round.

Comment: As I have understood it the noun changes depending on if it is in N, G., D., I. or L. class --> (дом/дома/дому/дом/домом/домe)

Comment: Yes, that's what declension is all about (they're called "cases" and not "classes"; a "noun class" is something else, a more general term for gender that includes similar categories in languages that don't base it around masculine/feminine/neuter). You just have to learn noun declension the same way you've learned adjective declension; whether there's an adjective accompanying the noun is, like I said, not part of the equation.

Comment: I found this article quite comprehensive: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_declension

Comment: @Joshualotz That's from the MTC TALL Language guide.

Answer (score 8):

Hopefully this chart is not too overwhelming, but if you just focus on the Adjectives and Nouns columns, it should be fairly simple. You have to learn the noun declensions, just like the adjective declensions. The Spelling Rules and Hard/Soft Indicators will help you to know exactly how to spell the endings.

[image: Grammar chart 1a]

Comment: Great chart. What is the source?

Comment: @joshualotz It's something I made a long time ago.

Comment: +1 for such dedication )))

Comment: You can download all of the charts here: https://reynoldsnlp.com/ReynoldsGrammarCards_15Jul2013.pdf https://reynoldsnlp.com/ReynoldsGrammarCards_15Jul2013BW.pdf

Comment: Oh my goodness!! thank you so much! Just the kind of organized information that I have been looking for!

Comment: reynoldsnlp Thank you so much for generously sharing your charts. They have been very helpful to me.
Best wishes,
Jan A